# Driver not in list and official plugin unhelpful - how to print plain text to HP from Android?

Tags: printing

I have a phone with Android Pie (LineageOS 16) and the HP Print Service plugin, and an HP OfficeJet X476 printer. (Which isn't an old model, under 3 years old office model). I often need to print text files such as plain text emails or downloaded XML files. My problem is that I cannot work out how to resolve the following printing quandary:

- HP Print Service states that it prints plain text only from an app with a "print" menu item, not from the "share" menu. Unfortunately many apps including some I can't easily change, only provide a share menu for printing.
- HP's FAQ comment "[Can I print if my app does not have a print option?](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c04024231)" acknowledges this but isn't helpful. It says "Yes but only photos and PDF" *(3rd FAQ item at this time)*. Their forum [says the same](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-Connected-Mobile-Printing-and-Cloud-Printing/Can-t-print-plain-text-files-on-Android-with-HP-Print/td-p/7127765).
- I've therefore looked at other well-known printing apps, such as StarPrint. The problem with *those* is, they need a driver selected, and my printer doesn't appear in the list of HP printers. So I can't select it. If there is some kind of generic (or generic IPP) driver, or an Android-specific driver rather than generic "Linux" on [HP's product page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-officejet-pro-x476-multifunction-printer-series/5276617/model/5146491), I can't see that, either.
  (If I do find and install a driver, I'm hoping it'll appear in StarPrint's list for selection, but can't be sure.)

Is there an easy way of *any* kind to print plain text files from my phone? Or do I have to either convert them to PDF every time, or move them over USB to my desktop?

What can I do, to print plain text and emails easily from my phone, ideally via its share menu?